# Can´t delete a row from a table with Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

When I try to delete a row from a table, using TypeScript, the following error is raised:

> **TS2339**: Property 'deleteRow' does not exist on type 'HTMLInputElement'.

```js
let tableElement = (<HTMLInputElement><any>document.getElementById(tableId));
tableElement.deleteRow(index);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have `HTMLInputElement`, but you mean `HTMLTableElement`.